# Html2canvas print screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, html2canvas

I have this piece of code in .aspx that should print the selected part of my web function.

```
           <div id="test" class="body-content animated fadeIn">
                <a href="javascript:getScreenshot()"> Get Sreenshot </a>
                <script>
                    function getScreenshot() {
                        html2canvas(divprint, {
                            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                                var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
                                $('#test').html('<img src="'+canvasImg+'" alt="">');
                            }
                        });
                        var printContent = document.getElementById("test");
                        var printWindow = window.open("", "","left=50,top=50");
                        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
                        printWindow.document.write("<script src=\'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js\'><\/script>");
                        printWindow.document.write("<script>$(window).load(function(){ print(); close(); });<\/script>");
                        printWindow.document.close();
                    }
                </script>
                ...
```

But clicking the the text "Get Sreenshot" nothing happens. Do you understand why?
When I remove

```
                       html2canvas(divprint, {
                            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                                var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
                                $('#test').html('<img src="'+canvasImg+'" alt="">');
                            }
                        });
```

it works more or less well

Comment: Did you load all libraries? What is the error in your console?

Comment: I've donne the in the cmd "npm install html2canvas" besides that nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of html2canvas uses promises rather than the 'onrendered` callback.
eg.

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector('#my-thing')).then(function(canvas) {
  // do something with canvas here.
  console.log(canvas);
});
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks! Do you know how to fix the problem of color change and zoom?

Comment: What problem with color change and zoom? I see nothing in your question about that.

Comment: See the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878872/html2canvas-color-change-and-zoom